# OpenCV Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

Full Code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2

# load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread("jurassic_world.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("preview", image)

# initialize the AKAZE descriptor, then detect keypoints and extract
# local invariant descriptors from the image
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()
(kps, descs) = detector.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
print("keypoints: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))

# draw the keypoints and show the output image
cv2.drawKeypoints(image, kps, image, (0, 255, 0))
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_akaze.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("preview", image)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imshow'
```

So I've tried to research an answer. There is a similar question on this site but I tried to do what they said and it didn't help: Here is what I did

- Ran as sudo
- added cv2.waitKey(0) after both imshow
- changed it to cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF (I have no idea what this is all about but I read somewhere that you have to do that for 64bit machines which mine is)
- I have commented out the imshow, everything else works. I get the desired result. But imshow seems like it's not installed or something :/

I am sorry I am such an idiot. And I am stabbing at the dark. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try copying the opencv libs to /usr/include, then try again

Comment: See if you've named a file the same thing as some important module.

Comment: @JeruLuke: Don't quote-format stack traces.

Comment: In terminal run `pkg-config --cflags --libs` and post results here.

Comment: @user2357112 just wanted to highlight the error message

Comment: I have try  and get the following message : `OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`

Comment: @Dadep You've not built opencv with gui support.

Comment: @Jeru-Luke Where is the opencv libs to begin with

Comment: @Zindarod I get: Must specify package names on the command line

Comment: @MichelleBergin Sorry, `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`. Did you build OpenCV from source or install from repository?

Comment: @Zindorad I used this site, http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/-I/usr/local/include/opencv 
-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_video -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_face -lopencv_latentsvm -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_reg -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal

Comment: @MichelleBergin There's no `libopencv_highgui.so` file. You did not build opencv with gui support.

Comment: @MichelleBergin That's it. You should've mentioned that at first. :)

Comment: @Zindarod Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the output of `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`:

> -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_video -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_face -lopencv_latentsvm -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_reg -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal

There's no `libopencv_highgui.so` present. You mentioned in the comments that you disabled VideoIO.

Follow [this link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) for best way of building OpenCV.